Caret model after multiple imputation with mice
I need help to fit a Neural network model (with caret R package) for a multiple imputed (m=5) datasets. I have performed the imputation and then run the models in the different imputed datasets. However, is there a more straightforward way to pool estimates? I need for example the ROC curve for the final model in a testing data set (validation external dataset) and other metrics and it would be perfect to have one unique model.
#MULTIPLE IMPUTATION
library(mice)
imputedData<-mice(training[,2:27], m=5, maxit=50, seed=500) 

idataset1<-complete(imputedData, action=1L)
idataset2<-complete(imputedData, action=2L)
idataset3<-complete(imputedData, action=3L)
idataset4<-complete(imputedData, action=4L)
idataset5<-complete(imputedData, action=5L)


#CARET MODEL
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, classProbs = T, savePredictions = T, sampling = "rose")

modelnnet1<-train(class ~., data=idataset1[,c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6","class")], method="nnet", trControl=control, metric="Sens", maximized=TRUE)
modelnnet2<-train(class ~., data=idataset2[,c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6","class")], method="nnet", trControl=control, metric="Sens", maximized=TRUE)
modelnnet3<-train(class ~., data=idataset3[,c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6","class")], method="nnet", trControl=control, metric="Sens", maximized=TRUE)
modelnnet4<-train(class ~., data=idataset4[,c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6","class")], method="nnet", trControl=control, metric="Sens", maximized=TRUE)
modelnnet5<-train(class ~., data=idataset5[,c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6","class")], method="nnet", trControl=control, metric="Sens", maximized=TRUE)




Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78502255/6574038
